# My prefix is true, My suffix is there for you

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix is there for true.
- My suffix is there for you.
- My infix is all I've got.
- Is my whole after not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> Really

- My prefix is there for true.

> Something that is 'real' is true

- My suffix is there for you.

> An 'ally' is someone who is there for you

- My infix is all I've got.

> Literally 'all'

- Is my whole after not?

> "Not 'really'"